# How to install SELinux policy for guix-daemon.service on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, systemd, selinux, readonly, guix

After installing Guix, how do I install the bundled SELinux policy, which is intended to allow the `guix-daemon.service` to run?

To install Guix 1.3.0 on Fedora 34 Workstation, I used the [shell installer script](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/html_node/Binary-Installation.html):

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/plain/etc/guix-install.sh
$ chmod +x guix-install.sh
$ sudo ./guix-install.sh
```

The script completed successfully. I hid its hints and installed the [name service cache daemon](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/html_node/Application-Setup.html#Name-Service-Switch-1):

```
$ sudo dnf install nscd
$ sudo systemctl enable nscd
$ sudo systemctl start nscd
```

Unfortunately, I cannot [proceed with installing `glibc-locales`](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/html_node/Application-Setup.html#Locales-1) because `guix-daemon.service` is not running:

```
$ guix install glibc-locales
hint: Consider installing the `glibc-utf8-locales' or `glibc-locales' package and defining `GUIX_LOCPATH', along these lines:

     guix install glibc-utf8-locales
     export GUIX_LOCPATH="$HOME/.guix-profile/lib/locale"

See the "Application Setup" section in the manual, for more info.

guix install: error: failed to connect to `/var/guix/daemon-socket/socket': No such file or directory
$ systemctl status guix-daemon
× guix-daemon.service - Build daemon for GNU Guix
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-08-19 21:12:26 EEST; 2h 29min ago
   Main PID: 793 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

сер 19 21:12:26 fedora systemd[1]: Started Build daemon for GNU Guix.
сер 19 21:12:26 fedora systemd[793]: guix-daemon.service: Failed to locate executable /var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/current-guix/bin/guix-daemon: Permission denied
сер 19 21:12:26 fedora systemd[793]: guix-daemon.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/current-guix/bin/guix-daemon: Permission denied
сер 19 21:12:26 fedora systemd[1]: guix-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
сер 19 21:12:26 fedora systemd[1]: guix-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сер 19 23:35:07 fedora systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service:12: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
сер 19 23:35:07 fedora systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service:13: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
```

According to [the manual](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/SELinux-Support.html):

> Guix includes an SELinux policy file at `etc/guix-daemon.cil` that can be installed on a system where SELinux is enabled, in order to label Guix files and to specify the expected behavior of the daemon…

The folks on the `#guix` channel at Libera Chat helped me to figure out that the above instruction is for the manually compiled Guix from git. For Guix installed with the shell installer script, I had to look for the file in `/gnu/store`:

```
$ find /gnu -name guix-daemon.cil
/gnu/store/0iii8i1lc4wg3wccs1db7y7d8lg80i04-guix-1.3.0/share/selinux/guix-daemon.cil
$ cd /gnu/store/0iii8i1lc4wg3wccs1db7y7d8lg80i04-guix-1.3.0/share/selinux/
$ sudo semodule -i guix-daemon.cil
```

Now, [the manual says](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/SELinux-Support.html):

> Then relabel the file system with `restorecon` or by a different mechanism provided by your system.

I tried:

```
$ sudo restorecon -vR /gnu
```

This returns lots of

```
restorecon: Could not set context for /gnu/…:  Read-only file system
```

For example:

```
$ find /gnu -name guix-daemon.service
/gnu/store/0iii8i1lc4wg3wccs1db7y7d8lg80i04-guix-1.3.0/lib/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service
$ sudo restorecon -v /gnu/store/0iii8i1lc4wg3wccs1db7y7d8lg80i04-guix-1.3.0/lib/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service
restorecon: Could not set context for /gnu/store/0iii8i1lc4wg3wccs1db7y7d8lg80i04-guix-1.3.0/lib/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service:  Read-only file system
```

And the daemon still cannot start.

My guess is that the issue is related to SELinux configuration or how Fedora handles it, but I do not understand it to be able to investigate it myself. Searching Guix issue tracker for ["Read-only file system" "SELinux"](https://issues.guix.gnu.org/search?query=%22Read-only%20file%20system%22%20%22SELinux%22) returned just two issues which are not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the guix install script you posted and it looks like it's creating a mount point via systemd to mount /gnu . The part of the install script which does this is

> { # systemd .mount units must be named after the target directory.
> # Here we assume a hard-coded name of /gnu/store.
> # XXX Work around https://issues.guix.gnu.org/41356 until next release.
> if [ -f "~root/.config/guix/current/lib/systemd/system/gnu-store.mount" ];
> then
> cp "~root/.config/guix/current/lib/systemd/system/gnu-store.mount" 
> /etc/systemd/system/;
> chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/gnu-store.mount;
> systemctl daemon-reload &&
> systemctl enable gnu-store.mount;
> fi

So this means that you would have to have a file called **gnu-store.mount** in systemd. I snooped a little more than found out that it has the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Read-only @storedir@ for GNU Guix
DefaultDependencies=no
ConditionPathExists=@storedir@
Before=guix-daemon.service

[Install]
WantedBy=guix-daemon.service

[Mount]
What=@storedir@
Where=@storedir@
Type=none
Options=bind,ro
```

If you look at Options=bind,ro , it's definitely read only so you would need to change it to rw, remount and then relabel with restoreconn. Judging by the description, it should not work like this, but I would try it. I hope this helps

Comment: I tried changing `ro` to `rw` in `/etc/systemd/system/gnu-store.mount` and rebooting, but it still was mounted as `ro`. I unmounted it with `sudo umount /gnu/store`. Then `restorecon` was able to complete with messages like `…Relabeled /gnu/store/… from unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:guix_daemon.guix_store_content_t:s0`. So, I believe, the policy is applied now. Still cannot run the daemon, so I will have to look for other issues now.

Comment: After installing this policy, I [cleared the remaining issues with `setroubleshoot`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665599/423679) till the daemon started. (Now looking how to allow `guix-daemon` to remount in SELinux.)