# How to allow "guix-daemon" to "remount" in SELinux?

Tags: fedora, selinux, automounting, guix

I've [installed Guix](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/html_node/Binary-Installation.html#Binary-Installation) and [installed the bundled SELinux policy manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665410/423679). But [according to Ricardo Wurmus](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-guix/2021-06/msg00096.html), as of 30 June 2021:

> There are really just two ways: either 1) disable SELinux (or set it to permissive mode) or 2) install/debug/reinstall the SELinux daemon policy that is included with Guix.
>
> The daemon policy is *not* installed with the binary installation method because it is known to be incomplete. You would need to get a copy of the Guix sources and configure it. The file you want is called “etc/guix-daemon.cil”. To debug it you would need to install it, set SELinux to permissive mode, run the daemon, and then check the audit log for errors.

There is an [open issue for SElinux guix-daemon.cil file](https://issues.guix.gnu.org/39172), which suggests a patch that seems already incorporated in the file bundled with my installation.

I installed `setroubleshoot` and kept restarting the `guix-daemon.service` while following the suggestions popping up in notifications. The daemon finally started after:

```
$ sudo chcon -R -t guix_daemon.guix_daemon_conf_t /var/guix/
$ sudo chcon -R -t guix_daemon.guix_profiles_t /var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/current-guix
$ sudo chcon -R -t guix_daemon.guix_profiles_t /var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/current-guix-1-link
```

But I still cannot proceed with [installing `glibc-locales`](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/html_node/Application-Setup.html#Locales-1):

```
$ guix install glibc-locales
hint: Consider installing the `glibc-utf8-locales' or `glibc-locales' package and defining `GUIX_LOCPATH', along these lines:

     guix install glibc-utf8-locales
     export GUIX_LOCPATH="$HOME/.guix-profile/lib/locale"

See the "Application Setup" section in the manual, for more info.

guix install: error: remounting /gnu/store writable: Permission denied
```

The SELinux diagnostics tool informs that "guix-daemon" is not allowed "remount" access to "filesystem" and suggests:

```
# ausearch -c 'guix-daemon' --raw | audit2allow -M my-guixdaemon
# semodule -X 300 -i my-guixdaemon.pp
```

But `ausearch` fails on this:

```
$ sudo ausearch -c '(x-daemon)' --raw | audit2allow -M my-xdaemon
compilation failed:
libsepol.hierarchy_add_type_callback: guix_daemon doesn't exist, guix_daemon.guix_daemon_conf_t is an orphan
libsepol.hierarchy_add_bounds: 1 errors found while adding hierarchies
```

How can I allow `guix-daemon` to remount the filesystem in SELinux?

Answer (score 0):

I turned on the permissive mode and used Guix for a while. SELinux support is apparently still a work in progress. `setroubleshoot` regularly notifies of various issues. Running Guix with SELinux in permissive mode seems the only practical solution at the moment.

([To turn on the permissive mode permanently](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/changing-selinux-states-and-modes_using-selinux), edit `/etc/selinux/config` and reboot.)